# Why does a range query on a segment tree return at most ceil(log_2 N) nodes?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, segment-tree

If an array A[1..N] is represented using a segment tree having sets in each interval, why does a range query [L..R] returns at most ceil(log_2 N) sets (or disjoint intervals)?

If came across this statement while reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22075025/10820849).

To quote:

> Find a disjoint coverage of the query range using the standard segment
>   tree query procedure. We get O(logn) disjoint nodes, the union of
>   whose multisets is exactly the multiset of values in the query range.
>   Let's call those multisets s_1, ..., s_m (with m <= ceil(log_2 n)).

I tried searching for a proof, but couldn't find it on any site. Can anyone help me prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Each node represents some power of 2^n elements where n is the height of the node. The segment tree never uses 2 neighboring nodes, because then if it can use two neighbors it will use their parent. Also, because ranges are continuous it will never use 2 nodes in one layer and some node that is below that layer and represents some range in between these 2 nodes. Therefore on each layer, there will be selected at most 2 nodes. Segment tree is made up of O(log n) layers, therefore, each query uses O(log n) nodes.

**EDIT 1:**

The actual bound of cell(log_2 N) is incorrect, and here is one of the examples:[image]
In this picture there is a segment tree for an array of length 8. If we make a query [1,6] (zero-based indexes) it will use 4 vertices (they are black on the image), and `4 > ceil(log_2(8)) = 3`

Comment: This gives you an asymptotic upper bound of O(logn) and not the precise ceil(log_2 N).