# Sorting n sets of data into one

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

I have n arrays of data, each of these arrays is sorted by the same criteria.

The number of arrays will, in almost all cases, not exceed 10, so it is a relatively small number. In each array, however, can be a large number of objects, that should be treated as infinite for the algorithm I am looking for.

I now want to treat these arrays as if they are one array. However, I do need a way, to retrieve objects in a given range as fast as possible and without touching all objects before the range and/or all objects after the range. Therefore it is not an option to iterate over all objects and store them in one single array. Fetches with low start values are also more likely than fetches with a high start value. So e.g. fetching objects [20,40) is much more likely than fetching objects [1000,1020), but it could happen.

The range itself will be pretty small, around 20 objects, or can be increased, if relevant for the performance, as long as this does not hit the limits of memory. So I would guess a couple of hundred objects would be fine as well.

**Example:**
3 arrays, each containing a couple of thousand entires. I now want to get the overall objects in the range [60, 80) without touching either the upper 60 objects in each set nor all the objets that are after object 80 in the array.

I am thinking about some sort of combined, modified binary search. My current idea is something like the following (note, that this is not fully thought through yet, it is just an idea):

- get object 60 of each array - the beginning of the range can not be after that, as every single array would already meet the requirements
- use these objects as the maximum value for the binary search in every array
- from one of the arrays, get the centered object (e.g. 30)
- with a binary search in all the other arrays, try to find the object in each array, that would be before, but as close as possible to the picked object.
- we now have 3 objects, e.g. object 15, 10 and 20. The sum of these objects would be 45. So there are 42 objects in front, which is more than the beginning of the range we are looking for (30). We continue our binary search in the remaining left half of one of the arrays
- if we instead get a value where the sum is smaller than the beginning of the range we are looking for, we continue our search on the right.
- at some point we will hit object 30. From there on, we can simply add the objects from each array, one by one, with an insertion sort until we hit the range length.

My questions are:

1. Is there any name for this kind of algorithm I described here?
2. Are there other algorithms or ideas for this problem, that might be better suited for this issue?

Thans in advance for any idea or help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People usually call this problem something like "selection in the union of multiple sorted arrays". [One of the questions in the sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607945/how-to-find-the-kth-smallest-element-in-the-union-of-two-sorted-arrays?rq=1) is about the special case of two sorted arrays, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753345/finding-kth-smallest-number-from-n-sorted-arrays?lq=1) is about the general case. Several comparison-based approaches appear in the combined answers; they more or less have to determine where the lower endpoint in each individual array is. Your binary search answer is one of the better approaches; there's an asymptotically faster algorithm due to Frederickson and Johnson, but it's complicated and not obviously an improvement for small ranks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the links you provided! I will start with my implementation and see how it performs! Thanks again!