# Big O complexity of this loop

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

If I have

```
int i;
for(i = 1; i < n; i *= 2) //n is the size of an array passed to the function
{
  //O(1) code here
}
```

What is the Big O complexity? The "i *= 2" bit is confusing me. I tried operation counting but now I'm even more confused.

Comment: Look at the last slide of [this](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like O(log(n)), because you iterate not over the whole sequence, but use power-of-two steps.

Answer (score 1):

complexity is O(log<sub>2</sub>(N))

Basically your 'i' doubles every iteration so after 1 iteration it's 2, then 4, then 8.  so if n = 2<sup>8</sup> then the loop will iterate (roughly) 8 times.

Comment: To be clear, this is the number of loop iterations, not the big-O complexity.

Comment: Eric, can you elaborate on the difference?

Comment: @Ashalynd's answer has the big-O complexity: it is O(log(n)) (no base, no subtraction). O(log2(N)-1) = O(log2(N)) = O(log(N))` (any base), and the canonical representative of this complexity class is `O(log(N))`.


Actually, upon looking at your answer more closely, it appears you have `log2(N)-log2(N) = 0` as the complexity.

Comment: Thanks - I made some minor edits to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be halving the steps each time, so you'd end up with O(log n), where n is the total number of iterations. See this: [What would cause an algorithm to have O(log n) complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152890/what-would-cause-an-algorithm-to-have-olog-n-complexity)

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is `O(log n)`.

You can rewrite the loop to
`for(x = 0; pow(2,x) < n; x++)` so `x < log n`. (`pow` should compute `2x`)