# What is the time complexity of this do-while loop?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

```
int count=0;
do
{
    count++;
    n=n/2;

}while (n>1);
```

I'm having trouble seeing the pattern here.
Even when plugging in numbers for n and then plotting out each basic operation.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I want the worst case here.

Comment: Are you familiar with logarithms?

Comment: try 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64...

Comment: In practice, it is O(1) because `INT_MAX` is a constant and the growth is so slow.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152890/what-would-cause-an-algorithm-to-have-olog-n-complexity

Answer (score 3):

First step is to divide `n` with `2`. So you get `n/2`. Now, you divide it again with `2`, if `n/2 > 1`, and you get `n/4`. If `n/4 > 1` you do it again, and you get `n/8`, or better to write it as `n/(2^3)`... Now if `n/(2^3) > 1` you do it again, and you get `n/(2^4)`... So, if you do it `k` times, you get `n/(2^k)`. How to calculate `k` to so you get `n/(2^k) ≤ 1`? Easy:

```
n/(2^k) ≤ 1
n ≤ 2^k
ln(n) ≤ k
```

So, your algorithm needs `O(ln(n))` iterations to exit the loop.

In your code, `k` is `count`.