# How is maximum key compare in binary search (1+log(n)) not log(n)?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search, logarithm

I was re going through a more versatile explanation of BS. Which has a preposition that maximum number of key compare in a binary search is (1+log(n)). I tried to form an intuition as to how is that possible. I understand the ruining time of BS is (log(n)). Also i speculate that the worse time/maximum key lookups will happen in scenario when we search for  a element which is not present in the array. But each time i go over a hypothetical array doing a BS i end up with (log(n)) compares/steps never more than that. Here is the code which was used to form that preposition.

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] a, int key){
     int lo = 0, hi = a.length-1;
     while (lo <= hi){
         int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;

         if (key < a[mid]) 
            hi = mid - 1;
         else if (key > a[mid]) 
            lo = mid + 1;
         else 
            return mid;
     }
     return -1;
 }
```

Probably my speculation is wrong or i am missing some point. If you could explain how maximum possible key compares would be (1+log(n)) it would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different way to think about what you're doing. Rather than thinking of binary search as searching over the elements of the array, think of binary search as searching over *the separators between the elements in the array*. Specifically, imagine numbering the array like this:

```
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
   |  0  |  1  |  2  | ... | n-1 |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Now, number the separators:

```
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
   |  0  |  1  |  2  | ... | n-1 |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
   0     1     2     3 .. n-1    n
```

Notice that there are n+1 total separators, one before each element and one after the very last element.

Whenever you do a binary search, you're probing the index of the middle *separator* (do you see why?) and throwing half of the separators away. You can [only throw half of a collection of k items away log<sub>2</sub> k times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9153420/501557) before you're down to a single remaining element. This means that the number of probes needed will be ⌈log<sub>2</sub> (n+1)⌉, and it happens to be the case that

> log<sub>2</sub> n < ⌈log<sub>2</sub> (n+1)⌉ ≤ log<sub>2</sub> n + 1,

so the "1 + log n" bit ends up arising more from "throw away half the separators" than from other sources.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that even when you have only 1 element, you still have to guess it, because it is possible that the target is not in the array. So we need to add on the +1 for the last guess when we are down to the final remaining element.

It may be clearer if you think about when `n=1`. We still need 1 guess, but `log_2(1) = 0`. So we need to add a `+1` to fix up the formula.

When `n` is not a power of 2, we can just go up to the next higher power of 2. For an array whose length is 1000, the next higher power of 2 is 1024, which is 10. Therefore, for a 1000-element array, binary search would require at most 11 (10 + 1) guesses.

> Why?

In the worst case, binary search would need 10 steps to separate the remaining numbers and 1 final step to check whether the only one number left is what you want, or it's not in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine an array of size 8.

```
l=0, h = 7, mid =  0 + (7-0)/2 = 3   go right
l=4, h = 7, mid =  4 + (7-4)/2 = 5   go right
l=6, h = 7, mid =  6 + (7-6)/2 = 6   go right
l=7, h = 7, mid =  7 + (7-7)/2 = 7   go left  
l=7, h=6 ====> terminates
```

> Total comparisons = 1 + Log 8 = 4

EDIT1: Imagine this array and use a pen and paper and trace out the above steps. Search for value 13.

```
index:      0  1  2  3  4  5  6   7   
            ------------------------------
element:    1  3  5  6  7  9  11  15
```

Comment: can you elaborate it a bit by taking a array of size 8 and deciding upon a element you are searching

Comment: Think of a size 8 array. And imagine searching for an element wherein you have to select the above middle indices. Best way to understand is to use pen and paper :-)